# Build a class to create an object with variable key

Tags: javascript

I want to create an object with variable key with the help of class instance.
I have tried by the following code

```
class ACL {
    constructor(key){
        this[key] = {
            read: false,
            write: false,
            delete: false
        }
    }

    setRoleReadAccess(key, value){
        [key] = {
            read: value,
        }
    }
    setRoleWriteAccess(key, value){
        [key] = {
            write: value,
        }
    }
    setRoleDeleteAccess(value){
        [key] = {
            delete: value,
        }
    }
}

const userACL = new ACL("1234");
userACL.setRoleReadAccess("1234", true);
userACL.setRoleWriteAccess("1234", true);
console.log(userACL);
```

But i am getting this error `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Invalid attempt to destructure non-iterable instance`

i am expecting the following console output

```
ACL {
 "1234": {
    read: true,
    write: true,
    delete: false
  }
}
```

Can anyone tell me how can resolve this

Comment: what is `[this.key]` in the constructor?

Comment: yes i am passing in constructor now

Comment: change `[this.key]` to `this[key]` and tell me what happens

Comment: @FranciscoSantorelli getting same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `[key] = {}`, you are trying to do a destructuring, which doesn't work because you can't destructure an object that way. It only works on arrays.

What you need is an assignment to `this[key]`.

```js
class ACL {
  constructor(key) {
      this[key] = { 
          read: false,
          write: false,
          delete: false
      }
  }

  setRoleReadAccess(key, value){
      this[key] = {   
          ...this[key],
          read: value,
      }
  }
  setRoleWriteAccess(key, value){
      this[key] = {   
        ...this[key],  
        write: value,
      }
  }
  setRoleDeleteAccess(key, value){ 
      this[key] = {  
        ...this[key],  
        delete: value,
      }
  }
}

const userACL = new ACL("1234");
userACL.setRoleReadAccess("1234", true);
userACL.setRoleWriteAccess("1234", true);
console.log(userACL);
```

Answer (score 3):

`[this.key] =` and `[key] =`  are trying to do iterable destructuring on what follows the `=`, but you can't do iterable destructuring on plain objects, they aren't iterable.

```
class ACL {
    constructor(key) {
        this[key] = { // ***
            read: false,
            write: false,
            delete: false
        }
    }

    setRoleReadAccess(key, value){
        this[key] = {   // ***
            read: value,
        }
    }
    setRoleWriteAccess(key, value){
        this[key] = {   // ***
            write: value,
        }
    }
    setRoleDeleteAccess(key, value){ // ** I added a missing `key` parameter here
        this[key] = {   // ***
            delete: value,
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess from his comment he 's passing `key` through the constructor

Comment: @AlanOmar - Sigh, yeah, that wasn't there before. I'll update.

Comment: now I am passing key in constructor

Comment: @AvinashAnshu - Yeah, I've updated.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I tried again but getting same error 

class ACL {
    constructor(key){
        this[key] = {
            read: false,
            write: false,
            delete: false
        }
    }

    setRoleReadAccess(key, value){
        [key] = {
            read: value,
        }
    }
    setRoleWriteAccess(key, value){
        [key] = {
            write: value,
        }
    }
    setRoleDeleteAccess(value){
        [key] = {
            delete: value,
        }
    }
}

Comment: const userACL = new ACL("1234");
    userACL.setRoleReadAccess("1234", true);
    userACL.setRoleWriteAccess("1234", true);

Comment: @AvinashAnshu - Look again at the `***` marked lines above. You've missed off the change and you still have just `[key] =` in some places in that code.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thanks its working now it is because of marked lie was missing